# sql query - to rent a car (php)

Tags: php, mysql

Im new to php and sql and having trouble writing a query.

I've already accomplished a query that show/get unrented cars.
And it looks this:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM cars c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
          SELECT * 
          FROM reservations as r
          WHERE r.car_id = c.id AND
          (r.res_from <= '2017-12-08 02:53:59' AND r.res_to >= '2017-12.09 23:58:59') OR
          (r.res_from <= '2017-12-08 23:59:59' AND r.res_to >= '2017-12.09 23:58:59') OR
          (r.res_from >= '2017-12-08 23:59:59' AND r.res_to <= '2017-12.09 23:58:59')
          );`
```

[image: After choosing dates a list of available cars appears]

The question is:  how to write a query that rent a car given from_date - to_date and a user/customer need enough points(money) to rent a specified car.

[link to my database http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/170f7f4/5](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/170f7f4/5)

I tried something like this. Is this the right way to go?

```
    SELECT * FROM cars as c, reservations as r, users as u,
    WHERE HAVING c.id = r.car_id AND
                 r.user_id = u.user_id AND
          (res_from <= '2017-12-08 02:53:59' AND r.res_to >= '2017-12-08 02:53:59') OR
          (r.res_from >= '2017-12-08 23:59:59' AND r.res_to <= '2017-12-08 23:59:59' )
```

.... what next?

And want to click on a car (as can be seen in the attached picture) and then chose a rent date.

Answer (score 0):

Use JOINS

```
SELECT * FROM cars as c
LEFT JOIN reservations as r ON c.id = r.car_id
LEFT JOIN users as u ON r.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE ...
etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT c.* FROM cars AS c
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT r. * FROM reservations AS r
               WHERE r.res_from >= '2017-12-09 23:58:59' 
               AND r.res_to <= '2017-12-18 23:58:59'
              )

             AS r ON c.id = r.car_id
             WHERE r.car_id is null;`

I think this one might work.